# How to return a CompletableFuture<MyType<T>> from a CompletableFuture<AnotherType<T>>

Tags: java, jackson, java-http-client

I am attempting to implement a generic REST client as below. I have my own model to represent the HTTP response as Response T . Here T is the return type from the service call and it could be just T or List of Ts. Below code does not compile and that is where I need help. You can suggest if you know any better ways to accomplish the same task.

```
@Override
    public <T> CompletableFuture<Response<T>> getAsync(UriOptions endpoint, Headers headers) {
        var builder = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(endpoint.getAbsoluteUri())
                .GET();
        for (var entry : headers.getMessageHeaders().entrySet()) {
            builder.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        var request = builder.build();
        var response = httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return response.thenComposeAsync(r ->
            try {
                 new Response<T>(
                        r.statusCode(),
                        HttpUtils.headersToMap(r.headers().map()),
                        objectMapper.readValue(r.body(), new TypeReference<T>() {
                        }),
                        HttpUtils.isSuccess(r.statusCode()), r.uri()
                );
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        );
    }
```

```
public class Response<T> {
    private T content;
    private int statusCode;
    private boolean isSuccessful;
    private String statusDescription;
    private Exception exception;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private URI uri;
```

And eventually call the method as below,

```
@Test
    void getAsync() {
        // Arrange
        var baseUrl = settings.get("api.baseUri");
        var options = new UriOptions(baseUrl, "students/6277aade6f047803e8ae4bcf");
        var headers = new Headers(new HashMap<String, String>(), new HashMap<String, String>());

        // Act
        var response = restApiClient.<Student>getAsync(options, headers);

        // Assert
        response.thenAccept((r) ->
        {
            Assertions.assertEquals(200, r.getStatusCode());
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything that completes the request.  I don't have time to work it through right now, but I'd expect the function that is the argument to thenComposeAsync to be provide the Response\<T\> result by a call to complete() on some future.  Probably you need to separate the future you return to your caller from futures you use in your implementation.

Comment: Your lambda in `thenComposeAsync` does not return anything. It needs to return a `CompletableFuture<SomeT>` (and it requires curly braces. An expression lambda cannot contain a try block directly)

Comment: I do not want to call complete() or get(). I think it will make the method blocking / synchronous

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "How to return a CompletableFuture<MyType> from a CompletableFuture<AnotherType>" from the title: you'd generally use [`thenApply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) and friends:

```
final CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() => "42");
final CompletableFuture<Integer> intFuture = future.thenApply(Integer::parseInt);
// or future.thenApply(s -> Integer.parseInt(s));
// or future.thenApply(s -> { return Integer.parseInt(s); });
```

Looking at your specific code, there seems to be a syntax error in the lambda of `thenComposeAsync` (which composes two *CompletableFuture* instances, so its lambda needs to return another CompletableFuture instance, not the value itself).

And since it is not doing any expensive work, transforming the value asynchronically is overkill. A simple `thenApply` will do the job just fine:

```
return response.thenApply(r -> {
    try {
         return new Response<T>(
                r.statusCode(),
                HttpUtils.headersToMap(r.headers().map()),
                objectMapper.readValue(r.body(), new TypeReference<T>() {}),
                HttpUtils.isSuccess(r.statusCode()), r.uri()
        );
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

If you insist on using `thenCompose`, then you need to wrap your result in another CompletableFuture:

```
return response.then(r -> {
    try {
         return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Response<T>(
                r.statusCode(),
                HttpUtils.headersToMap(r.headers().map()),
                objectMapper.readValue(r.body(), new TypeReference<T>() {}),
                HttpUtils.isSuccess(r.statusCode()), r.uri()
        ));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: knittl, Still having an issue, I have opened another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167067/java-lang-classcastexception-class-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-class-po

Comment: @Rasika the linked question is deleted